# How to redirect to the same page after comment

Tags: java, javascript

```
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info no-radius" type="submit"  onClick="saveMessage('new')" id="query_btn_margin">
          <i class="ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
                Add Comment
        </button>
    </span>
```

In the conversation field,after Add Comment the page redirects to the next page..how it will be fixed on the same page..??

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain more

Comment: <script>

 function saveMessage(){
       
    $('#query-message').submit();   
 }

</script>

Comment: On the header section..there is a message email box..in which Inbox and Sent fields shows their values..like a simple gmail..after write message..then if we want to comment on that particular message..then all comments should be show on the same page..but after comment the page redirects to the main page ( Inbox / Sent) page..I want to stay on that page..so how it will work ??

Answer (score 2):

```
You can write this code after completing your task,write this line.
window.location.href = "newjsp.jsp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You already call this **`onclick="saveMessage('new')"`** function add at the end of the function,

```
window.location = '/'
```

or you may use this,

```
window.location = window.location.host;
window.location = window.location.href;
```

even more you use jquery in your page use,

```
$(window).attr("location","http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to go to next page (next page content is on same page with display:none) after addition of comments...

```
<input type='button' name='add_comment'  id='add_comment' value='ADD COMMENT'/>
```

When user click on above button call below js code

```
$('#add_comment').click(function(){
    $('.currentpage_div_id_to_hide').hide();
   $('.nextpage_div_id_to_show').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make sure you can use .js file:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
            window.location.href = "newjsp.jsp";
        });
    });
</script>
```